# Creating a PDF from HTML using C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I've heard there is a way to create PDF files. I need a C# framework but anything other than iTextSharp.

Please note I wish to use C# .net framework only, not iTextSharp or any other utility.

Comment: Can't you just look at his souce code?

Comment: Very good relationships if your colleague doesn't help you ...

Comment: @Ladislav, I was just writing the same thing. Productivity must be skyrocketing.

Comment: PDF is an open format (as is postscript), so in theory your coworker could have written code using only StringBuilder that spits out raw postscript.  But for any sort of non-trivial text-based documents, he would have needed to either use a library such as itextsharp, or waste lots of time.

Comment: @Marko its called Web 3.0 Ultimate Cloud Collaboration Suite

Comment: @mark if i could, i wouldnt be posting this question to get down vote...  :((

Comment: @user287745 you've just framed your question very badly, maybe you can re format it. Maybe a mod with some higher powers can edit it?

Comment: You can try NOV Text Editor:https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-rich-text-editor-control-overview.aspx It can help you convert HTML to PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Pdf Sharp ==> http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Its all open source and free under the MIT license, in case you want to invent your own library you can see how they did it.

The API is similar to GDI+, Also, they have something called MigraDoc which can be used to create a document in memory and then render it to RTF, XPS, or PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CutePDF.  Since your co-worker refuses to help you I doubt highly he wrote a framework for C#, he probably is doing what most of us do when we want to make PDFS.